# How to run code formatting tool on every commit in feature-branch with git rebase

Tags: git, automation, git-rebase, code-formatting, feature-branch

We introduced `php-cs-fixer` into our codebase and I want to rebase an existing feature branch. We enforce a semi-linear history, so every feature branch is rebased before merging without squashing the whole branch.

To keep the history clean I want to run the tool on every commit in the branch, but keep the commits in place and not have the code style change with a later commit, but already be correct in every commit that will later be merged into the `main` branch.

Using `git rebase --exec "./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix" main` results in a lot of conflicts that I don't want to fix manually, as it is very error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this semi-automatic approach:

I started with `git rebase -i main` and replaced every `pick` operation with an `edit` operation. (Vim: `:%s/pick/edit/`)

Instead of conflict resolving manually, I use `git checkout REBASE_HEAD .`, to replace the working tree with the non-code formatted version and then run the code formatting tool again. (In this example `./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix`)

Because the rebase behavior is slightly different if a conflict occurs, you need to follow up with different commands to complete the current commit based on the state:

#### This command if you encounter a normal "edit" breakpoint:

Looks like

```
Stopped at abc123...  [Commit Message...]
You can amend the commit now, with

  git commit --amend 

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

  git rebase --continue
```

After checkout and code format, amend current commit and continue rebase:

```
git commit --amend -a --no-edit && git rebase --continue
```

Complete one-step command:

```
git checkout REBASE_HEAD . && ./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix && git commit --amend -a --no-edit && git rebase --continue
```

#### This command if you encounter a rebase conflict:

Looks like this (hints might be colored):

```
Auto-merging [File]
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in [File]
error: could not apply abc123... [Commit Message]
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply abc123... [Commit Message]
```

After checkout and code format, stage changes and let `git rebase --continue` amend the commit:

```
git add -u . && GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase --continue
```

Complete one-step command:

```
git checkout REBASE_HEAD . && ./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix && git add -u . && GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase --continue
```

If you use the wrong command, the end result will be the same, but you will lose some commits.

Sadly, I couldn't figure out a way to use `git rebase --exec`(`REBASE_HEAD` isn't defined during the exec command?) or a way to automatically use the correct resolve command.

I'm sure there is a better solution, but I couldn't find it, so I present mine here.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue and this is one of the first hits on google. I solved it using [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/tree/main) and its contrib tool [lint-history](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/contrib/filter-repo-demos/lint-history):

> This is a simple program that will run a linting program on all non-binary
> files in history.
>
> [...]
>
> To run eslint --fix on all .js files in history:
>
> `lint-history --relevant 'return filename.endswith(b".js")' eslint --fix`

Do note, that those tools rewrite your entire git history so do a backup first. Also, if you already published your changes, you better coordinate the change with your team. I had some issues running it on Windows, but using WSL worked fine.